# Edit object with ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

when I Edit a class with Virtual Icollection, the Icollection become null.
I don't use the Icollection in the view, so I tried,hiddenfor with elementat().

Model

```
public class Event
{
    public Event() { EventId = Guid.NewGuid(); }

    public Guid EventId { get; set; }

    public string contenu { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookedUser> BookedUsers { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Event
if (Model.BookedUsers.Count != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.BookedUsers.Count(); i++)
    {
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BookedUsers.ElementAt(i).BookedUserId)

    }
}
```

Comment: If you're not using it in the View, why bother including it in the ViewModel?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I usually hide object on view when I don t use it, It is the way I find, to not lose the data. and I looking for a way to do it with a Icollection.

Comment: The model and view are already created, I looking for a way without changing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can't use `ICollection`, as Razor can't parse the call to `ElementAt(i)` in order to create a properly indexed input name. You need a list, so you can pass `m.BookedUser[i].BookedUserId`.

This is an important reason to use view models, as the entity, the class that is persisted to the database, is often at odds with what the view needs. Create a view model like:

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public string contenu { get; set; }
    public List<BookedUser> BookedUsers { get; set; }
}
```

And then map to/from this and `Event`.